# ubuntu 12.04 shutdown hanging

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

When trying to shutdown ubuntu 12.04 it shows the dialog box of shutdown but after clicking it nothing happen I have to click on the power button to shut down

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command instead of the power button:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

It is not a solution but it might save your computer and data until you solve the problem.

Comment: yeah Im trying the same thing but how many days will this error be. I have tried to update and my updates are up to date

Comment: Can anyone answer me Why this bug has encrypted to my system only